# Wouter routing React Link state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using the Wouter package to create routes in my react application.

My mission is to send the data of an object of my AnyComponent component from the state property of Link component to access that value through TestComponent.
Whenever I try to make a console.log from TestComponent I get undefined, even if these components are in the same path.

These would be the three files that I am using...

```
//App.jsx
import TestComponent from '././test/TestComponent.jsx';
import {Route} from "wouter";

return (
    <>
      <Route path="/test" component={TestComponent} />
    </>
  )

//AnyComponent.jsx

import { Link } from 'wouter';

const AnyComponent = () => (
    <div>
        <Link href="/test" state={{ testValue: "Hello, world!" }}>Go to Test Component</Link>
    </div>
);

export default AnyComponent;


// TestComponent.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'wouter';


const TestComponent = () => {
    let { state } = useLocation();
    console.log(state);  //undefined
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Test Component</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: I just checked, `useLocation()` returns an array not an object, unfortunately i couldn't found any exported value called `state`.

Comment: Thanks for answer @SankaSanjeeva, perhaps you know another way could I accomplish this goal?

Comment: I haven't used this library but I always use router params or search params to pass data. I use react-router-dom library.